# SQL query to group by day but with another condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data something like this:

```
| visitor_id | time       | my_flag |
| 1          | 01-01-2017 | 1       |
| 2          | 01-01-2017 | 1       |
| 1          | 01-02-2017 | 2       |
| 3          | 01-02-2017 | 2       |
```

etc...

I want to group all visitors in one day but based on a flag. The flag can have two values, 1 or 2. So I need something like

```
| 12 | 01-01-2017 | 1 |
| 10 | 01-01-2017 | 2 |
| 34 | 01-02-2017 | 1 |
```

I have

```
select v.visitor_id v.time, v.flag
from my_table as v
group by DAY(v.time) having flag=1;
```

But I am not able to figure out how to add multiple conditions (flag=1 and flag=2)? Any pointers?

Comment: can you show the input as well?

Comment: have you tried just doing a multiple group by? ex. group by DAY(v.time), v.flag

Comment: @vkp added sample input. Joe.Ingalls thanks, I haven't tried that. :) Let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
select v.visitor_id v.time, v.flag
from my_table as v
where v.flag in (1,2)
group by DAY(v.time), v.flag
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v.time, 
       v.flag, 
       COUNT(v.visitor_id)
FROM my_table as v
GROUP BY v.time, 
         v.flag;`
```